# Install Phalcon on MAMP PRO 4 (OS X Sierra + Homebrew)

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, phalcon, mamp-pro

I'd like to start to use Phalcon on my server but I'm getting some issue installing it on MAMP PRO.

1) The server is running PHP 7.1 located in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1

1.1) on terminal:

```
php -v return 
PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2017 15:09:57) ( NTS )
```

2) inside this directory I created a subdirectory /include/php and here here I downloaded the content of http://php.net/get/php-7.1.6.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror

3) 
    cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/include/php

3.1) 
    ./configure --without-iconv

3.2) I got "Thank you for using PHP"

4) From info listed here [Phalcon:install](https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux) (OSX + Brew )

```
# OS X (Homebrew)
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/php
brew install php7x php7x-phalcon
```

5) Compiling Phalcon as

```
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

Then I got: Thanks for compiling Phalcon!

6) Now I have to tell to server to use the new extension so I created a info php page to get the right place to update php.ini

```
<?php
echo php_ini_loaded_file();
phpinfo();
?>
```

and it says...

```
Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
...
PHP Version 7.1.1
...
```

7) Finally on terminal I update the php.ini

sudo vi /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini

I got an empty file (!) so I try to load the php7.1.1.ini and it it's full so I add at last line

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

8) restart the server ( to be sure I restart MAMP PRO)

But it doesn't works... reloading the phpinfo() Phalcon is missing... and if I go on my Phalcon pages I got

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcom\Config' not found
```

If I run

```
php -v
```

I got this warning:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/phalcon.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/phalcon.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2017 15:09:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

But if I comment the last line in php.ini the warning disappear.

Can you help me to understand what's wrong ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can to build by hand. Just git clone cphalcon:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.5 (cli) (built: May 13 2017 13:30:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/phpize
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sergheiiakovlev  admin  35 May 16 15:07 /usr/local/bin/phpize -> ../Cellar/php71/7.1.5_17/bin/phpize

$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/php-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sergheiiakovlev  admin  39 May 16 15:07 /usr/local/bin/php-config -> ../Cellar/php71/7.1.5_17/bin/php-config

$ cd build
$ ./install

$ php --ri phalcon

phalcon


Web framework delivered as a C-extension for PHP
phalcon => enabled
Author => Phalcon Team and contributors
Version => 3.2.0
Build Date => Jun 21 2017 20:33:47
Powered by Zephir => Version 0.9.9-868cb1f92b

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phalcon.db.escape_identifiers => On => On
phalcon.db.force_casting => Off => Off
phalcon.orm.events => On => On
phalcon.orm.virtual_foreign_keys => On => On
phalcon.orm.column_renaming => On => On
phalcon.orm.not_null_validations => On => On
phalcon.orm.exception_on_failed_save => Off => Off
phalcon.orm.enable_literals => On => On
phalcon.orm.late_state_binding => Off => Off
phalcon.orm.enable_implicit_joins => On => On
phalcon.orm.cast_on_hydrate => Off => Off
phalcon.orm.ignore_unknown_columns => Off => Off
phalcon.orm.update_snapshot_on_save => On => On
phalcon.orm.disable_assign_setters => Off => Off
```